# What is the proper way to request a user to sign a transaction from the frontend?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Let's say I have an arbitrary contract deployed on the ethereum network. Now I want to build a frontend that interfaces with it using the user's wallet. Obviously I cannot have access to the user's private key and execute the transaction myself (as I would in a testing situation). What is the proper way to prompt the user to sign a transaction that is created from the front-end form info without touching their private keys? (using ethers.js)

Comment: So more specifically, what is the right way to connect to a wallet's JSONRPCPROVIDER, and do all wallets have JSONRPCPROVIDERs connected to their accounts? https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/-%23-JsonRpcSigner

Comment: Use Web3js or ethers.js to interact with the user wallet, you understand??

Answer (score 0):

You can use ethers (or web3js) and make your life even easier with something like [web3modal](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal).

In order to interact with the user's wallet you will need to ask them to connect to your app. For web3modal the documentation is pretty straight forward, but there are examples for native [metamask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/Getting-Started.html) as well. If all goes well, you'll get access the instance of the provider.

Ethers: the library splits that instance into two concepts, a provider and a signer. The [provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/) is the one for reading data, while the signer is the one for sending transactions and doing user related stuff.

Web3js: this mixes the [provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/) with the signer so you'll only have to keep track of one. P.S. web3Modal will actually yield this type of provider by default.

```js
// Example with web3Modal and ethers

const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
  network: "mainnet",
  cacheProvider: true,
  providerOptions: {} 
});

const web3Provider = await web3Modal.connect();
const ethersProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3Provider)
const ethersSigner = ethersProvider.getSigner()
```